# Did I just find a bug in rails Date format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, format

In trying to parse a date, I have been racking my brain for hours:

```
Date.today.to_s
=> "06/07/2011" 

Date.today
=> Tue, 07 Jun 2011 

Date.parse Date.today.to_s
 => Wed, 06 Jul 2011 

Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default]
 => "%m/%d/%Y"
```

The default format for to_s is different than the default format for parsing? Why would they do this to me?

Using Rails 3.0.5 with Ruby 1.9.2-p180

**UPDATE**
So thanks to your answers, I realize that the DATE_FORMATS is a rails thing while Date.format is using the ruby library (correct?). Is there a way then to parse dates/times with the default DATE_FORMAT without using strptime?

Comment: Doesn't happen to me in Rails 3.1rc1.

Comment: @Veeti -- If you do something like `Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%m/%d/%Y"` and then run the code you'll see it. He probably has an initializer setting this default date format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally, `Date.today.to_s` would return "2011-06-07", but since you set a default date format, it's using "06/07/2011" instead.

`Date.parse` easily recognizes the YYYY-MM-DD format, but when it sees 06/07/2011 it thinks that's really DD/MM/YYYY (not MM/DD/YYYY as you're expecting -- keep in mind that `Date.parse` knows nothing about Rails' default date format you set. The default date format is only for Rails' outputting of `Date.to_s`).

You can force it to parse a MM/DD/YYYY date like this:

```
Date.strptime(Date.today.to_s, "%m/%d/%Y")
# => Tue, 07 Jun 2011
```

Comment: But shouldnt Time.zone.parse at least use this information? The default date format is only for output and not for parsing?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the to_s method uses a [locale option](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/locale/en.yml) to determine how to write the date.

I dont see how this is an issue though. Date.parse uses heuristics to parse the date so sometimes it will get it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The Chronic gem ([link](http://chronic.rubyforge.org/))solves pretty much all date parsing issues (and yes, they can be quite annoying).

```
Chronic.parse("06/07/2011")
#=> 2011-06-07 12:00:00 +0000
```